# AMD FirePro AMDGPU-PRO drivers on 18.04 and OpenCL

Tags: drivers, 18.04, amd-graphics, opencl, amdgpu-pro

I'm trying to run DaVinci Resolve on Ubuntu while using AMD FirePro W5500 card. 
DaVinci Resolve requires OpenCL to work so I installed 18.04.2 (I've got minimal installation without any updates) as it is required by [Radeon™ Pro Software for Enterprise](https://www.amd.com/en/support/professional-graphics/firepro/firepro-wx000-series/firepro-w5000) witch is basically some version of AMDGPU-PRO.
I think I managed to install it, this is what I get from `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  amdgpu-pro     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

and a result of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` is

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn LE GL [FirePro W5000] [1002:6809]
    Subsystem: Dell Pitcairn LE GL [FirePro W5000] [1028:0b06]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

I'm also geting errors from DaVinci Resolve

`No OpenCL boards available on chassis 1.`

and

`CRITICAL_PREF: DaVinci Resolve could not find any OpenCL capable GPUs. Would you like to review and update your DaVinci Resolve Hardware Configuration? Please ensure that appropriate GPU drivers are installed and your DaVinci Resolve hardware is configured appropriately.`

software is basically unusable as there is no image, unfortunately I'm not sure is it OpenCL fault or anything else, but I decided to go one step at a time and try to solve OpenCL issue first.
If I understand correctly I have AMDGPU-PRO installed but system doesn't use PRO version and because of this there is no OpenCL support (I installed OpenCL with drivers as described on [AMD installation guide](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).
Can I blacklist / delete / switch drivers? And how should I do it?

I understand that Blackmagic doesn't support Ubuntu but they do CentOS unfortunately I had exactely same problem with CentOS and honestly I prefer Ubuntu and apparently it is possible to get it working as soon as I get drivers right.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?, 3 months ago since you wrote this question. I have the same exact card. Please post the output of 'clinfo' command. Install It using apt if you don't have It. Also provide the files under /etc/openCL/vendors

Comment: I never got it working and I give up as AMD didn't update drivers for this card for ubuntu 18.04 updates. Thanks for asking. Since then I updated my system, I'm using open drivers shipped with ubuntu and had to give up on using any OpenCL acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of these and I was testing on my own recently.

The way to go is to configure the card using `amdgpu` instead of `radeon`. This article https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMDGPU explains how to do it.

Use the parameters `radeon.si_support=0` and `amdgpu.si_support=1`. Set them in `/et/modprobe.d` in the files `amdgpu.conf` and `radeon.conf`.

If it does not work, set these properties in the `/etc/default/grub` and make sure to execute `update-grub` to apply the changes. Once this is done, install clover OpenCL implementation (from mesa) together with the icd. This is an open implementation for OpenCL.

Do not expect wonders from this library. It barely supports OpenCL 1.1, not even 1.2. Things like LuxMark are working for me, while others like folding@home are simply not working. It's the only solution right now. Everything which is GCN 1.0 is not well supported. GCN 1.2 and up are well supported (AMD claims that but I can't test it) using either amdgpu-pro or orca OpenCL implementation.

Comment: FYI I tested this configuration, executed LuxMark and I could execute some renders using clover implementation. Yes. It's not ideal I know, as clover supports only 1.1 not 1.2 OpenCL, but at least It's something. In windows we have full 1.2 OpenCL support, but here It's just clover and It's not very stable, for example I tried to run It with folding@home and It's crashing

Comment: That's another problem in long term I'll need something reliable and most likely I'll need to invest in new card with up to date support and drivers. But thank you very much for the answer. I'll try to get set up a system for testing again.